# three.js / OrbitControls is not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js

When i try to import OrbitControls.js the following:

I get the `Cannot use import statement outside a module` error

So, I use :

`<script type="module" src="OrbitControls.js"></script`>

but this time I get:

```
ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined
```

HTML body:

```
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <h1>Open Spaceport Container (.drc):</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="fileInput">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre id="decoderType"><pre>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="DRACOLoader.js"></script>
   <script src="geometry_helper.js"></script>
   <script type="module" src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
       <script>
        "use strict"
        


      // Configure decoder and create loader.
          var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
          const loadManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing ES6 module with non-module code which is not valid. Do it like so:

```js
<script type="module">

import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js';

import { DRACOLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

// your actual app code

// Configure decoder and create loader.
const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

</script>
```

I suggest you convert your custom `geometry_helper.js` to a ES6 module, too.