# THREE.JS Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera);
camera.position.set(200, 0, 0);
controls.update();

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 32, 32);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.129.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

When I run my javascript code. I get the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined".
I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155393/three-js-orbitcontrols-is-not-defined) about it, but it doesn't seem to help.
Any ideas?

My OrbitControls.js is in the same file under the three.js file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got your code running without errors by importing OrbitControls and defining your renderer at the top and passing it into OrbitControls.

Edit, I added a second snippet that was adapted from a three.js example on their site that I think adds the yellow sphere you're looking for.

```js
let camera, controls, scene, renderer;

init();
//render(); // remove when using next line for animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
  scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(400, 200, 0);

  // controls

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

  controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

  controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

  controls.minDistance = 100;
  controls.maxDistance = 500;

  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

  // world

  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 32, 32);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00
  });
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(sphere);




  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  controls.update(); // only required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true

  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

```js
let camera, controls, scene, renderer;

init();
//render(); // remove when using next line for animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
  scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(400, 200, 0);

  // controls

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

  controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;

  controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

  controls.minDistance = 100;
  controls.maxDistance = 500;

  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

  // world

  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 32, 32);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00
  });
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(sphere);




  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  controls.update(); // only required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true

  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work ! but it is strange, I should have a yellow sphere appearing... Do you have any idea why it doesn't?

Comment: I've added a second snippet adapted from an example on their site that I think adds the yellow sphere you're looking for. I'm not immediately sure why it's not showing up in your original code.